# Solving ODE with python

Tags: python, ode

I've tried to solve a 1-st order ode equation using scipy.integrate.ode.

dh/dx = - s0 * (1 - (hn/h)^3)/(1 - (hc/h)^3)

The initial condition is x = 0 and h = 10.
s0 = 0.001 when x < 15000, 
s0 = 0.0005 when x >= 15000.

hn = (f*q^2/8*g*s0)^(1/3) 
hc = (q^2/g)^(1/3)

f, q, g are constant.

The method I used is node bdf, but the result I got is different than the answer solved by matlab.
The answer should be like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18438495/result.png

Can anyone see the problem?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def waterdepth(t, y):
    if t < 15000:
        s0 = 0.001
    elif t >= 15000:
        s0 = 0.0005
    q = 3.72
    f = 0.03
    g = 9.81
    hn = (f*q*q/8*g*s0)**(1.0/3.0)
    hc = (q*q/g)**(1.0/3.0)
    return -s0 * (1.0 - (hn/y)**3)/(1.0 - (hc/y)**3)

y0 = 10.0
t0 = 0.0

solver = ode(waterdepth).set_integrator('node', method = 'bdf') 
solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
dt = 100.0
t1 = 25000

x = []
h = []
while solver.successful() and solver.t < t1:
    x.append(solver.t)
    solver.integrate(solver.t + dt)
    h.append(solver.y)

    plt.plot (x, h)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return -s0 * (1.0 - (hn/y)**3)/(1.0 - (hc/y)**3)
```

is different from the equation on top.

```
dh/dx = - s0 * (1 - (hn-h)^3)/(1 - (hc-h)^3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the notice. The equation in my python code is the correct one.